# Tab Escape Character Seems to Have No Effect

Tags: java

I was working on a simple card game and came across something strange. When I use this code:

```
System.out.println("Computer:\t"+6+" cards");
System.out.println("Player:\t"+7+" cards");
```

It ignores the tab in the second statement. I can easily fix this if I put in another table in like this:

```
System.out.println("Computer:\t"+6+" cards");
System.out.println("Player:\t\t"+7+" cards");
```

But I want to know why the first tab is ignored.

Comment: What do you expect the tab character to do?

Comment: I'd consider doing some research into `String` formatting (`String#format`) which will probably give you more desirable results

Comment: `Computer:` is 9 characters long, `Player:` is 7.  The next tab stop after `Player:` is simply one space wide (given a tab stop is typically 8 characters)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I think you've meant 4 instead of 8.

Comment: @user3707125 Not always

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks, I think I understand now.

Comment: @njasi would you please print sample output out of your program? Also, if you could print the results of `System.out.println("a\ta\ta\ta");` that would be helpful too. I'm suspicious that your `\t` isn't actually being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tab characters aren't actually getting ignored. The length of a printed tab character is up until the next position that is divisible by four. For example, see the output of this [IDEOne program](http://ideone.com/xgV3U0).

As you can see, the results of the following lines code:

```
System.out.println("a\ta\ta\ta");
System.out.println("ab\tab\tab\tab");
System.out.println("abc\tabc\tabc\tabc");
```

is as follows:

```
Line1:  a   a   a   a
Line2:  ab  ab  ab  ab
Line3:  abc abc abc abc
```

The length of a tab alone is 4. But printing a tab fills variable length whitespace until a position divisible by 4 is reached. The tab's filled space on the first line is 3, because `a` takes up 1 length, the tab's filled space on the second line is 2, because `ab` takes up 2 length, etc.

I hope that helps.

Comment: [A tab is eight spaces unless configured otherwise somewhere.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_Tab#Tab_characters)

Comment: Fair enough, I was just going off of the IDEOne default. There, it is 4.